# How to use Angular CLI and self-signed SSL certificate to serve over HTTPS in localhost on Ubuntu?

Tags: angular, ubuntu, https, openssl, angular-cli

I want to use Angular CLI and self-signed SSL certificate to serve over HTTPS in localhost on Ubuntu. My ubuntu version is 18.04.5 LTS.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create keys with this command inside `project-name/ssl/`:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:<no-of-rsa-bit> -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days <no-of-days>
```

Then just add this extra ssl param like this :

```
    "start": "ng serve --ssl true",
    "start": "ng serve --ssl",
```

This works, [but as the certificate is self-signed browser won't recognize it](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/112770/203979) :

[image]

And here is an awesome article showing how to install certificate in mac-systems : https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/